# Rxjs Transform API result Observable to another Observable in a service function

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, transform

I have a loader service whose result is `Observable<string>` which contains a CSV file. Each row represent a different entity of (e.g.) Person object, the comma separated parts represent the property of the person for example id, age, name, etc.

The loader service function is:

```
loadtTextFile(path: string): Observable<string>
```

The loadAllPerson service function is:

```
loadAllPerson(): Observable<Array<Person>>
```

I would like to call the `loadtTextFile` in a wrapper `loadAllPerson` where the required output is: `Observable<Array<Person>>`

How can I ensure that the service only returns when all rows of CSV are parsed into result `Observable<Array<Person>>`?

Probably at first we should wait for the *loader service* result, after parse it into the Person array and return the result in `Observable<Array<Person>>`

The following code part parse the content into Person Array, where the `contentObservable` is an `Observable<string>`

```
const contentObservable = this.fileLoaderService.loadtTextFile();

contentObservable.mapTo(fileContent => {
    const rowsOfContent = fileContent.split('\n');
    rowsOfContent.forEach((row: string) => {
      const cols = row.split(',');
      // has valid numeric value of id and age?
      if (!Number.isNaN(+cols[0]) && !Number.isNaN(+cols[3])) {
        const person = new Person(+cols[0], cols[1], cols[2], +cols[3], cols[4],
          cols[5], cols[6], cols[7], new Date(cols[8]));
        personData.push(person);
      }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(personData));
});
```

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

`map` operator is your friend. Try like this:

```
loadAllPerson(): Observable<Person[]> {
  return loadTextFile(PATH).pipe(
    map((csv: string) =>
      csv.split('\n')
         .map((rows: string[]) => rows.map((row: string) => row.split(',')))
         .map((table: string[][]) => 
           table.filter((cols: string[]) => !Number.isNaN(+cols[0]) && !Number.isNaN(+cols[3]))
                .map((cols: string[]) => new Person(+cols[0], cols[1], cols[2], +cols[3], cols[4], cols[5], cols[6], cols[7], new Date(cols[8])))
         )
    )),
  );
}
```